# Getting changed files back before commiting to branch

Tags: git, visual-studio

In `VS` I was working on a branch and I committed my changes before switching to another branch just in case to be safe.
Now I went back to first branch but in "`Changes`" section of `Team Explorer` those committed changes do not show anymore.
I do want them to still show because I need to do some code clean-up and review them. I also have some new changes too, all the same branch, just not commited those yet.
So how can I get everything to show in "Changes" section of `Team Explorer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the reset command to move back one commit.

In a terminal, you can run :

```
git reset --soft HEAD^    # the changes will stay in the index
                          # as if they were staged
# or
git reset HEAD^     # the changes will be on disk
                    # as if you had edited your files and not yet added them
```

Comment: Thank you I will try the second one now. I want it to look like they are just on my local and I have to commit everything again

Answer (score 0):

When you commit in Git, you are updating that branch of the project using your changes. Thus, the files you committed are no longer in "Changes", and shouldn't be, because "Changes" is meant  to show you what is different since the last commit.

It seems you want to be able to see what files have been changed when switching branches. You have a few options:

1. Stash your changes instead of committing them. This can be done in VS by clicking the three dots and then choosing **Stash**. You can reload these changes when you return to the branch. This might be better practice for you if you don't want to commit an incomplete file.
2. Download a plugin like [Git History](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.githistory) to see your previous commits in VS. This is better practice if you want to commit something and then see what was changed in the future entirely in VS.
3. Download GitHub Desktop. This automatically does both of the former options for you. If you don't care about having another application open while working, this might be best for you.

Comment: Thanks ok these are good suggestions for future.  But right now how do I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

In a directory under git, it is not possible to make changes and ignore them. Unless you put the contents of the folder elsewhere
so I advise you to be careful in writing commands

Comment: This is a useful hint in general but does not answer the specific question, which was specifically about Visual Studio.